# If function $f$ is differentiable at a point $a$, does it imply that $f'(a)$ exists?

Tags: calculus, definition

If function $f$ is differentiable at a point $a$, does it imply that $f'(a)$ exists?

I want to proof that if function $f$ is differentiable at a point $a$, then the function is continious at this point. I want to do this by using the multiplication rule for limits. For that I need to show that function $f$ has a finite limit at point $a$. I have read that function if is differentiable at a point $a$ if $f'(a)$ exists. However, it seems that it is not exactly what I need.

Thank you for your asnwers. I was a bit confused by how the definiton phrased.

I have an additional question: how does one know when "if" means "if and only if" and "if" means "if"?

Comment: $f'(a)$ is, by definition, the derivative of $f$ at $a$. So yes

Comment: Downvote. This is a most trivial notational question, the answer to which can be found practically anywhere.

Comment: I disagree with the down-vote and the vote to close the question.  How to prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ then $f$ is continuous at $a$ is a reasonable question.  And it is unreasonable to expect students posting things like this never to be confused about some of the details. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: "If" never means "if and only if", however, "if and only if" is sometimes written as "iff".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *definition* of "$f$ is differentiable at a point $a$" is that "$f'(a)$ exists".  So $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if $f'(a)$ exists.

(When you read that "function $f$ is differentiable at a point $a$ if $f'(a)$ exists", that was probably using the standard convention in mathematics that "if" actually means "if and only if" when making a definition.  That is, if you write "I define $f$ to be *differentiable* at $a$ if $f'(a)$ exists", you actually mean that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if and only if $f'(a)$ exists.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Then how does one know when "if" means "if and only if" and "if" means "if"?

Comment: It means "if and only if" when (and only when) it appears at the start of a _definition_, as in the example I gave.  The rationale is that if it actually just meant "if", you wouldn't be providing a complete definition at all--you would just be mentioning some sufficient conditions for your newly defined property to hold.

Comment: Why not to use "if and only if"? It seems to be less confusing.

Comment: It's just a standard convention; people use it because it is what they are used to hearing and reading, and it is briefer.  It is unfortunate how it can cause confusion among beginners, but it is not so easy to change the habits of thousands of mathematicians who have been trained to follow the convention.

Comment: In the definition of the limit we have the following part: $0<|x−c|<δ$  implies $|f(x)−L|<ϵ$. Am I correct to assume that the implication actually means implication?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  That's why I said "if" means "if and only if" only at the _start_ of a definition; that is, when it is connecting the term you are defining to its definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "at the start of a definition"?

Comment: I mean when it is the "if" connecting the defined term to its definition.  For instance, suppose I want to define "scrumptious functions".  I could write "A function is scrumptious if [...]", and only that "if" means "if and only if".  If the word "if" appears in the "[...]" somewhere, it just means "if".

Comment: Thank you. Now the situation is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

To say $f$ is differentiable at $a$ means that $f'(a) = \lim\limits_{h\to0} \dfrac{f(a+h) - f(a)} h$ exists.  That is a definition, not something requiring proof.

If you want to prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ then $f$ is continuous at $a$, you can do so as follows.

First, let us note that trivially $\lim\limits_{h\to0} \dfrac{f(a+h) - f(a)} h$ is the same as $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.  That that limit exists is another way of saying what it means to say $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \vphantom{\dfrac1{\displaystyle\sum}}$ exists (and that means it's a finite number, not $+\infty$ or $-\infty$) and $\lim\limits_{x\to a} (x-a)$ exists, the limit of the product exists and is equal to the product of the two limits:
$$
\lim_{x\to a} \left(\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \cdot (x-a)\right) = \left(\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\right) \cdot \left(\lim_{x\to a} (x-a) \right).
$$
The first limit is some finite number (since $f$ is differentiable at $a$) and the second is $0$.  Therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to a} (f(x)-f(a)) = 0.
$$
And given that, one can show that
$$
\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = f(a),
$$
so $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Should your displaymath read $\lim_{x\to a} \cdots$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it implies that $f'(a)$ exists and $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$. That's the definition of differentiability.

Comment: I think this is more suited as a comment than an answer

Comment: Why?  It answers the question, doesn't it?

Comment: @learnmore: I think your observation is more suited as an unspoken thought than a comment.

Comment: @kamil09875 Thank you for your answer. "More generally, if x0 is a point in the domain of a function f, then f is said to be differentiable at x0 if the derivative f ′(x0) exists". This is the definition from wikipedia. Why does it say "if the derivative f ′(x0) exists" and not "if and only if the derivative f ′(x0) exists"?

Comment: @user048983486: I have addressed that in my answer.  Saying "if" instead of "if and only if" is just a convention when stating definitions.